# How to chose the rectangle to solve $\int_{{ -\infty}}^{{\infty} } \frac{\mathrm{cos(x)}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} dx$ with residues?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to chose the rectangle to solve $\int_{{\textstyle\ -\infty}}^{{\textstyle\infty} } \frac{\mathrm{cos(x)}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} dx$ with residues?

I tried 2 options:

- Option 1: Rectangle lies on the x-axes
- Option 2: x-axes is in the rectangle

What is the correct option, and why it is? I become two different answers...
It's logic, because I used a different parameterization...

See pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your second approach, you neglected the pole at $-i\pi/2$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thnx!! I updated my answer... I still do not become the same answer for both options. Do you see the problem?